# How to install the PROcess Packages which is a tar file in R?

Tags: r

I tried for installing the PROcess package by following way:

```
>install.packages("/home/R-Packages/PROcess.tar.gz",repos=NULL)
```

Then following error occurs:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘Icens’ is not available for package ‘PROcess’
```

Then I have tried to install the Icens packages:

```
>install.packages("Icens")
```

Then following error occurs:

```
package ‘Icens’ is not available (for R version 2.15.3)
```

So Can anyone help me out of this problem and suggest some way so that I can able to install the PROcess packages.

Comment: See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Icens/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Icens package has been moved from CRAN to another repository: Bioconductor. [The Bioconductor page of Icens](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Icens.html) states that it can be installed using the following command:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Icens")
```